# Discord.js bot not loading image urls in MessageEmbeds(), was previously

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, embed

So one of my bots has a majority of it's commands contain imagery via the Discord.MessageEmbed() function, which has worked since I first tried it. Now, however, out of nowhere, the images no longer load in, however with my meme command (I have it set to log the image link) it does log the correct link. It is with all of my commands that contain imagery, as stated.

I have tried re-installing each of the packages the bot uses, and it still doesn't work. I tried looking it up online, however nothing applied to me

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the whole discord system at the moment. If you try sending a link, there won't be an embed either.
The discord team is actively working to fix the issue at the moment.